# how to send multiple ArrayList from a Servlet to JSP without using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, methods

I have to send three ArrayList from the servlet to jsp.
My problem is i cannot return three arrayList from the same method.

```
public ArrayList afficher(String s)
ArrayList <A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList <B> list2 = new ArrayList<B>();
//some operations

list.add(new A("aaa"));

list2.add(new B("bbbb"));

return list, list2;





ow can I proceed?
```

Comment: You can create `List<List<Object>>` Also you can use ModelAndView object and add all model inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store variables as attributes in [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), and retrieve them in your JSP. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049414/store-variable-for-jsp-usage) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your method with ModelAndView as return type.

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("welcomePage");
mav.addObject("list", list);
mav.addObject("list2", list2);
return mav
```

In that mav object you can add n number of models.

And on jsp you can access them using **`${list}, ${list2}`**.

```
@Data
@Builder
class Main {

    public List<List<Object>> getList() {
        List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(Arrays.asList(new A[]{new A("A"), new A("A1"), new A("A2")}));
        list.add(Arrays.asList(new B[]{new B("B"), new B("B1"), new B("B2")}));
        return list;
    }

}

class A {
    String name;

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class B {
    String name;

    public B(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```